# docker-maven-plugin not creating dockerfile

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

I am using docker-maven-plugin to create a dockerfile and docker image for a Java micro service. When I run the command `mvn package -DskipTest=true`, it does not create Dockerfile.

I am using docker-maven-plugin to create a dockerfile and docker image for a Java micro service. When I run the command `mvn package -DskipTest=true`. It runs successfully without any errors but it does not generate a Dockerfile. Looking at the messages emitted to the screen, it does not look like that plugin ran although it is configured in 'build'

Below is the configuration for the build task in pom.xml:

```
 <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>explorecali-${ec-profile}</imageName>
                    <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                    <entryPoint>["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=${ec-profile}", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <forceTags>true</forceTags>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        </build>
```

No error messages but no Dockefile. Below is are message emitted to screen when I run it:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.example.ec:explorecali >---------------------
[INFO] Building explorecali 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\fikhas\dev\spring\Ex_Files_Ext_Docker_Spring_Boot\Exercise Files\Ch05\05_05\explorecali\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\fikhas\dev\spring\Ex_Files_Ext_Docker_Spring_Boot\Exercise Files\Ch05\05_05\explorecali\target\explorecali-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ explorecali ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.576 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-07T13:25:58-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run "maven package docker:build" rather than just "maven package". In order to bind the docker build into a maven phase, you could also try something like this:

```
<execution>
<id>build-image</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>build</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
```

From https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#bind-docker-commands-to-maven-phases

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin to plugins

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
   <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also need to use dockerfile-maven-plugin instead of docker-maven-plugin(currently inactive)

```
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```