# How to generate the dockerfile for java based project?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am looking for generate the Dockerfile for java based project? I don't want to write it manually. Because for .NET projects in Visual Studio, there is a Docker plugin that can generate the Dockerfile once you build the project. Please help me understand if it's the same for Java projects as well.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.43.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>kbe-rest</name>
                        <build>
                            <assembly>
                                <descriptionRef>artifact</descriptionRef>
                            </assembly>
                            <dockerFile>Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>latest</tag>
                            </tags>
                        </build>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: i m pretty sure there are maven plugins for that, but what you dont want to specify in the docker file, you will have to specify to the plugin regardless? https://dmp.fabric8.io/

Comment: See also this link that uses a similar plugin https://stackoverflow.com/q/57399529/16034206

Comment: @experimentunit1998X, I will check this option.

Comment: wait, these are two different plugins. The second one is from [spotify](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md) but it seems that both support creating a docker file from a provided configuration so either one should work?

Comment: these are also valid options: https://medium.com/swlh/build-a-docker-image-using-maven-and-spring-boot-58147045a400

Comment: this video is also helpful to perform step by step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVnQydym9Gw

Comment: Hi @experimentunit1998X, I have tried to put all the fabric plugin in pom.xml file but docker file is not getting generated. I am updating the configuration in question section.

Comment: Hi OP, this section of the documentation says it should, though I cannot confirm if it is true for you? https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:build "When using this mode, the Dockerfile is created on the fly with all instructions extracted from the configuration given."

Answer (score 1):

Fabric8 maven plugin does not generate a Dockerfile on disk, it immediately builds the Docker container.

If you specify a `<dockerFile>` configuration, it assumes it's an existing external Dockerfile, and skips generating one.

An alternative is the Jib maven plugin from google: https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/jib. However, it also does not generate an actual Dockerfile, it generates the container image directly.